# how to get text from a TextInputEditText?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I have this for the TextInputEditText:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/textInputEditText"
    android:layout_width="335dp"
    android:layout_height="255dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:hint="@string/tells_us_your_behave"
    android:minWidth="4dp"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textColorHint="#757575"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="37dp"
    tools:visibility="visible"
    />
```

This is for the "Submit" button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="321dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:text="@string/submit"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:onClick="text"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.585"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ratingBar3"
    tools:ignore="OnClick" />
```

and I have this for the `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextInputLayout text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int x = Random();
        if (1 % 2 == 0) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
        else
        {   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);
        }

    }
    public static int Random() {
        Random x = new Random();
        return x.nextInt(100);
    }
    public void userlayout(View view){
        setContentView(R.layout.user_activity_layout);

    }

    public void activityAfterLogIn(View view){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        System.out.println(R.id.username);
    }

    public void text(View view) {
        text= findViewById(R.id.textInputEditText);
        setContentView(R.layout.talking);
        System.out.println(text);
        //ai.aici(text.getEditText().getText().toString(), view);
    }

    public void talk(View view){
        setContentView(R.layout.talking);
    }

}
```

I am trying to get the text from the TextInputEditText and send to a java class, I don t know what is wrong here.

Comment: What do you think `findViewById(R.id.textInputEditText)` returns? Why do you store it in a field of the type `TextInputLayout`?

Comment: I create the `TextInputLayout` field to store the string that will be in write in the text box and I was thinking that the `findViewById(R.id.textInputEditText)` will give me the text by the id sorry I a new into this

Answer (score 0):

**Add this below the findViewById line of code in the text public void method**

```
String getEditText = text.getText.toString();
System.Out.Println(getEditText);
```

Comment: no effect even after I tried

Answer (score 0):

Okay try to log it and see by adding this

```
Log.d("Edit Text", getEditText);
```

then input any string and check log

Comment: Where should I put this, sorry to ask

Comment: Below String getEditText = text.getText.toString();

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 public void text(View view) {
        text= findViewById(R.id.textInputEditText);
        setContentView(R.layout.talking);

        // Put this line
        myText = text.getText().toString();

        // Now check the Log 
        System.out.println(myText );
        Log.d("Edit Text value : ", myText );
       
    }
```

Hope this will work for you.